# How do you actually run cargo flamegraph on tests?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo, flamegraph

I have a test I can run as:

`cargo test tests::my_test -- --nocapture`

I am trying to profile it without any luck, [the docs](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph) claim that you can use one of the following:

```
# Profile unit tests.
# Note that a separating `--` is necessary if `--unit-test` is the last flag.
cargo flamegraph --unit-test -- test::in::package::with::single::crate
cargo flamegraph --unit-test crate_name -- test::in::package::with::multiple:crate
cargo flamegraph --unit-test --dev test::may::omit::separator::if::unit::test::flag::not::last::flag

# Profile integration tests.
cargo flamegraph --test test_name
```

I have tried them all:

```
cargo flamegraph --unit-test -- test::mytest
Error: crate has no automatically selectable target:
```

```
cargo flamegraph --unit-test my_crate -- test::mytest

error: unexpected argument 'tests::mytest' found

Usage: cargo flamegraph [OPTIONS] [-- <TRAILING_ARGUMENTS>...]

For more information, try '--help'.
```

```
cargo flamegraph --test tests::mytest -- --nocapture
error: no test target named `tests::mytest`.

Error: cargo build failed
```

The documentation is doing a very poor job of conveying what you are actually meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and after updating from `flamegraph v0.5.1` to `flamegraph v0.6.4` it worked as expected.

In my project (which has multiple bin and lib crates) the magic invocation was:

```
cargo flamegraph --root --dev --unit-test {the-crate} -- {the-test}
```